# Difference between "manejar" and "conducir"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, sinónimos

Today's word of the day on spanishdict.com is [despacio](http://www.spanishdict.com/wordoftheday/2227/despacio). There I found this sentence:

> A mi hermano le fastidia cuando la gente que quiere manejar despacio conduce en el canal de velocidad.

I perfectly understand the sentence, not least because they provide a translation.

I just wonder why they don't use *conducir* twice. I understand *manejar* as *to steer* (when it comes to cars) and that use feels strange.
I found a statement on the Internet claiming that *manejar* is Mexican colloquial for *to drive*. That would suggest, in conclusion, that the sentence above wouldn't be considered idiomatic in Spain.

So, what's the difference between these two words (in regard to driving)?
Is the use of *manejar* in the sentence above really more idiomatic than *conducir*?

Comment: The sentence is indeed written in American Spanish. *Manejar* points to that, but also *canal de velocidad* (we'd use *carril rápido* in Spain).

Comment: To avoid repetition, simplify the sentence with just one verb. In Spain we would say **"A mi hermano le fastidian los que van despacio por el carril rápido."**

Comment: @fedorqui olé tu celo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although they are *expressions* of the same sense (observing regional differences that have been mentioned), you must remember that these are *words* with different meanings.

**Manejar** involves taking action to get something. Originally, these actions were manual (*manos* = "hands"), and the word relates to *manipular* ("manipulate") and *maniobrar* ("maneuver").

**Conducir** involves carrying something in one direction. It derives from Latin "ducere" (to guide), and is related to *conducto* ("duct") and *conducta* ("behavior").

So, strictly speaking:

> Tú **manejas** el vehículo con las manos y los pies, para **conducirlo** por la calle hacia el trabajo.

ergo, you *maneuver* the vehicle to *drive* down the street to work.

Comment: +1 For explain both words with clear definitions.

Comment: The definitions are clear but the real (de facto) meanings are blurred.

Answer (score 15):

That's quite a weird phrase to me simply because I'm from Spain.

> *Manejar* is only used in Latin American countries; *conducir* is the only word for *drive* in Spain.

Also, this phrase must have been written by a person from South America because in Spain we use *carril* instead of *canal.*

Of course you can use *conducir* or *manejar* twice, but it sounds quite repetitive. If you don't want to use *manejar*, a person from Spain would say:

> A mi hermano le fastidia cuando la gente que quiere conducir despacio
> lo hace en el carril rápido.

I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: +1 For avoid use more than once the word _conducir_ in the sentence and add: _but it souns quite repetitive_ (which is true). Also, in Colombia is used too the word _carril_ instead _canal de velocidad_.

Comment: it's going to be so much "fun" traveling to spain next week, with all my mexican spanish knowledge. ;(

Comment: @sgroves Don't worry, everybody will understand you. Unless you use a lot of Mexican slang, of course; but just using a Mexican register will cause you no problem.

Comment: Just for the record, I am from Spain and my grandma used to say "manejar" instead of "conducir".

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that statement would sound funny in Spain, where indeed the speaker would have used `conducir` twice.

Latin American countries favor "manejar" (to handle or steer a vehicle, if you fancy it that way) instead of "conducir" but that doesn't mean that they don't know (or use) the word `conducir`.

In the same way, some these countries you would probably hear more "manejar el **carro**" or "manejar el **auto**", that also gives you a hint of where the speaker is from but this doesn't hold true for all Latin American countries.

My guess is that the speaker could have used `manejar` twice in your example, but to avoid repetition, he or she used "conducir" instead. What is interesting is that he/she used "manejar" for a person controlling the vehicle (fast/slow) and "conducir" for the action of the vehicle being controlled/positioned in a certain lane.

Also remember that the source you cite is an online resource, and not everything on the Internet is completely accurate and reliable (without any intentions to misrepresent that site). I wouldn't be too surprised if it is not completely consistent. As you can see, what sounds completely normal to just one of the many Spanish speaking countries can be a little bit (or completely) off in others. Whoever wrote that example is maybe trying to "show off" a little bit and include more vocabulary (sacrificing consistency).

Answer (score 4):

The difference between "manejar" and "conducir" is subtle, and, in spite of Rodrigo's explanation, is totally blurred by de facto usage, which varies wildly from region to region. By the way, I'd translate both as "to drive" more than  "to steer."

In Argentina, we understand, but rarely use, "conducir" for steering a vehicle. We'd prefer "manejar" for both:

- **manejar despacio**
- **manejar por el carril rápido / de alta velocidad** (instead of "en el canal de velocidad")

To avoid the repetition, we'd naturally say something like:

- ... cuando la gente que quiere **manejar** despacio **va** por el carril rápido
- ... cuando la gente que quiere **ir** despacio **maneja** por el carril rápido

Some replacements: "va" -> "elige ir", "ir" -> "viajar", "marchar"

Answer (score 2):

I would say there is no difference.  They have the same meaning in regards to driving a car.  "Manejar" is used in Latin America and "conducir" is used here in Spain.

But they can have different meanings sometimes.  For example, in Spain, "estoy conduciendo una grúa" means "I'm driving a crane," but "estoy manejando una grúa" means "I'm operating a crane."